# How to limit people with multiple project access querying a project through another project's billing?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

It has become apparent to me that who the query costs are billed to (at least when using UI) are dependant on the project selected up top.
I.e. if I query a dataset in 'project_a' but have selected 'project_b' at the top this query would be billed to 'project_b'.

([Who pays query costs on datasets across multiple users in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952773/who-pays-query-costs-on-datasets-across-multiple-users-in-bigquery) and https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#how_charges_are_billed)

Is there a way to limit this cross-billing occurring without completely removing people from other projects?

I am worried that if somebody forgets to switch their project at the top we could end up billing someone for another clients' work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly not, and it's the power of BigQuery, to separate the storage and the compute. If a user has the role jobUser on several projects and can view a dataset, they start a query job in any project where they have the role.

An ultimate solution could be to create a [VPC SC](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls) on each project. Like this, you prevent any data "exfiltration" from external projects. But this feature can bring much more problems than solve.